# Why did the Daleks use pigs to make pig-slaves?

Tags: doctor-who, genetic-engineering, dalek

In "Daleks in Manhattan" and "Evolution of the Daleks", Daleks from the Cult of Skaro use a genetic laboratory in 1930 Manhattan to turn residents of the slum of Hooverville into pig-slaves, which they use a labor and guards.

Why did the Daleks choose to use pigs for the human hybrids? A couple of things make me question this:

- Pigs aren't too genetically similar to humans.
- Pigs don't have many qualities that make them good fighters/workers, when compared to other animals.
- There aren't a lot of pigs in Manhattan.

There are much better choices out there. So why did the Daleks choose to make *pig*-slaves?

Comment: To answer the question in your title: because it's difficult to make _pig_-slaves out of horses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IANAMS, but I have worked with the odd Mad Scientist or two.

Pigs are more medically compatible with humans than you'd think:

> Pigs share a number of surprising comparable traits with humans. For
>   instance, we both have hairless skin, a thick layer of subcutaneous
>   fat, light-colored eyes, protruding noses and heavy eyelashes. Pig
>   skin tissues and heart valves can be used in medicine because of their
>   compatibility with the human body.

Quote is from [mnn.com](http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/stories/pigs-and-humans-more-closely-related-thought-according-genetic-analysis) and also references xenotransplantation article [on the same site](http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/stories/animals-could-one-day-become-human-organ-donors).

Insulin from pigs has also been used in humans; to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_(medication)) with emphasis mine:

> Insulin from [cow/horse/pig/fish] is effective in humans as it is
>   *nearly identical to human insulin* (three amino acid difference in
>   bovine insulin, *one amino acid difference in porcine*).

In addition, as any Babe could tell you, pigs are smarter than they look:

> Pigs can often outsmart dogs and are on about the same intellectual
>   level as our closest living relatives, chimpanzees, according to a new
>   paper.

(That's [discovery.com](http://news.discovery.com/animals/iq-tests-suggest-pigs-are-smart-as-dogs-chimps-150611.htm) describing [a paper](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/8sx4s79c) published in the International Journal of Comparative Psychology).

All in all, I think pigs would not be the worst choice the Daleks could have made.  In 1930's NYC, the half-pony, half-monkey hybrid was out of their reach.